# how to solve vtigercrm webform error message? {"success":false,"error":{"message":"Webform not found."}}

Tags: php, crm, vtiger

I have installed vtigercrm on my hostgator hosting when I create a webform from setting it did not show on html and on browser it display this error message.

I need step by step guide on creation of successful webform

error message I get is here

```
{"success":false,"error":{"message":"Webform not found."}}
```

Did any one know how to solve this. Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and here is the solution that I used. VTiger has an error in their code for displaying the right url for the action url.

Here is the original code...

`<form name="Webform Name" action="http://yourDomainName.commodules/Webforms/capture.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"…`

This is how the code should be…

`<form name="Webform Name" action="http://yourDomainName.com/modules/Webforms/capture.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"…`

Notice they didn't include the forward slash (/) after .com. Once that is put into place then the link works. Hope that helped.